# Netbeans project specific settings resetting

Tags: maven, netbeans

I am having a problem with my project specific settings resetting while I am working.

I am trying to configure my project to use the IDE wide formatting configurations, but after a small while the settings for the project are reset to use the default project specific settings.

I assume this is related to automatic build in the background doing something that is removing the project configuration file but I haven't found out anything more related to that.

Other points to note:

- The project is huge
- The project is maven configured
- I am the only one working in netbeans that I am aware of
- The Project has a parent maven project which I also have open in the IDE
- The Project is in a Git repository which I believe I have set up to ignore Netbeans config files.

Comment: There is usually a `nbproject` directory which has various files (XML) in it that has project specific data. Maybe take a copy of that when it's working and `diff` or use some other comparison tool after it appears to stop working to see if those files are being modified?

Comment: Are there any circumstances where Netbeans would not create the nbproject folder?  I am currently thinking that Netbeans is not saving the information of the project configuration to a file and I only see the correct behaviour while this is still cached in memory.

Comment: Do a search on your local system for `nbproject` and you should find it. It is *not always* in the same place as the source files for your project. I'm not sure what your set up is but it sounds to me like when you're synchronising files it's overwriting (or modifying) the XML files in `nbproject`. These are where NetBeans stores the project properties and configuration data.

Comment: Update on what I know so far - It appears that the settings are being kept in a file called nb-configuration.xml which seems to hold a list of deviations from the defaults.  When the option to use the netbeans global formatting options are set this file is deleted because it is no longer needed.  However, there doesn't seem to be anywhere that persists the decision to use the IDE formatting settings.  My workaround at the moment is to set up the project settings how I want them and import them into all of the sub-projects that I am using.